# How to use the getter of an enum?

Tags: java, android, object, enums, model

I have this model of an object called expenseType:

```
 public class ExpenseType {

        private String gridText;

        public enum type {
            FOOD(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_FOOD, R.drawable.food_blue, R.drawable.food),
            FLOWERS(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_FLOWERS, R.drawable.flowers_blue, R.drawable.flowers),
            GROCERIES(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_GROCERIES, R.drawable.groceries_blue, R.drawable.groceries),
            HOLIDAY(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_HOLIDAY, R.drawable.holiday_blue, R.drawable.holiday),
            PHARMACY(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_PHARMACY, R.drawable.pharmacy_blue, R.drawable.pharmacy),
            BILLS(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_BILLS, R.drawable.bills_blue, R.drawable.bills),
            CLOTHES(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_CLOTHES, R.drawable.clothes_blue, R.drawable.clothes),
            TRANSPORT(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_TRANSPORT, R.drawable.transport_blue, R.drawable.transport),
            ITEMS(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_ITEMS, R.drawable.items_blue, R.drawable.items),
            OTHERS(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_OTHERS, R.drawable.others_blue, R.drawable.others);

            private String expenseKey;
            private int drawableBlue, drawableWhite;

            type(String expenseKey, @DrawableRes int drawableBlue, @DrawableRes int drawableWhite) {
                this.expenseKey = expenseKey;
                this.drawableBlue = drawableBlue;
                this.drawableWhite = drawableWhite;
            }

            public String getKey() {
                return expenseKey;
            }

            public int getDrawableBlue() {
                return drawableBlue;
            }

            public int getDrawableWhite() {
                return drawableWhite;
            }
        }

        public ExpenseType(String gridText) {
            this.gridText = gridText;
        }

        public String getGridText() {
            return gridText;
        }

        public void setGridText(String gridText) {
            this.gridText = gridText;
        }
    }
```

The string gridText gets written inside a database, but I do not want to add the drawable values to the database as well, so I created that enum that has the drawable variation. Now, inside a recycle view adapter, how can I access the getDrawableBlue() from the enum so I can set an icon correspondent to my expenseType?

I have this code in the adapter:

```
private void checkSelect(ExpenseType expenseType) {
            if(positionSelected == getAdapterPosition()){
                gridIcon.setImageResource(????????);
                return;
            }
```

How can I access that getter instead of the ???????? so I can get my drawable value stored in that enum?

Comment: Just call the method on `expenseType`, nothing different from any other method call. For example `expenseType.getDrawableBlue()`

Comment: @Jesper I tried it, it doesn't work. If I write expenseType. , the hints only shows getGridText which is a getter of the object itself, not the enum. getDrawableBlue isn't there and is red if I manually type it

Answer (score 0):

`expenseType` seems to be of the class type `ExpenseType` but the enum you're refering to is the inner enum `type` (which should be renamed btw). Thus you'd need to either provide a field for `type` in `ExpenseType` and a getter for that and then call something like `expenseType.getType().getDrawableBlue()` or refactor your code (depends on what `ExpenseType` is meant to represent).

As for the renaming: the class `ExpenseType` has a field `gridText` which might indicate that it actually represents a cell. If that's the case I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
public class ExpenseGridCell {
   private String gridText;

   private ExpenseType type; //that would be your enum tyoe

   public ExpenseType getType() { 
     return type;
   }
}

//I'll move the enum to a separate class which makes it easier to use elsewhere (the outer class would be a "namespace" only anyway)
public enum ExpenseType {
   FOOD(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_FOOD,R.drawable.food_blue, R.drawable.food),
   ...;
}
```

If  `gridText` isn't a cell's text but the same for every type then you might want to merge the inner enum `type` into `ExpenseType`, i.e. something like this:

```
public enum ExpenseType {
   FOOD(Constants.EXPENSE_TYPE_FOOD, "Some grid text for food", R.drawable.food_blue, R.drawable.food),
   ...;

   private String gridText;
   private String expenseKey;
   private int drawableBlue, drawableWhite;

   //appropriate constructor and getters
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but what kind of object should that type field be?

Comment: @RFM I'll edit the answer but basically you'd rename the enum `type` to `ExpenseType`.

Comment: Great, this is the correct way of doing it. There is one more thing tho, now I set the drawable with: gridIcon.setImageResource(expenseType.getType().getDrawableWhite()) but I do receive a NullPointerException when I do this. Any idea why is that? The ImageView is linked by ID correctly and the problem seems to be somewhere else, because if I set a random R.drawable resource manually (basically replacing expenseType.getType().getDrawableWhite() with R.drawable.food for example), the image gets displayed correctly.

Comment: @RFM well you'd have to check where exactly the NPE occurs and what is null at the indicated line. I'd suspect `expenseType.getType()` returns `null` - did you set the `type` field to a non-null value? Note that enums behave much like classes in many cases. The most notable difference is that you'd create instances by listing the types in the enum and no other way.

Comment: Never mind, I realised I was never iterating though my types. I fixed the problem. Thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a glitch in your class design.

Your enum `type` is a nested class in your `ExpenseType` class. 
(Note: as it's an enum, it's implicitly a `static` nested type).

In order for you to be able to invoke the accessors of a `type`, you will need to reference its specific type somehow.

One way to do so would be to have a `type` as instance field of `ExpenseType`, pretty much like the `String gridText`.

You would then need to bind a specific `type` type to your `ExpenseType` instance (I know, this gets semantically confusing but I didn't name your variables :).

In other words, each instance of `ExpenseType` has its own `type` field assigned with one type of... errr.. `type`.

So instance 1 of `ExpenseType` has a `FOOD` value for its `type`, instance 2 of `ExpenseType` has a `FLOWERS` value for its `type`, etc.

You could  then add a getter and reference the `drawableBlue int` in `checkSelect` by invoking:

```
// assuming field type can't be null
expenseType.getType().getDrawableBlue()
```